# Where to point mobilefirst application build path to worklightconsole or project.war?

Tags: worklight-server, ibm-mobilefirst, contextpath, war

Currently having problem where to point mobilefirst application to worklightconsole context path or project.war context path ?

the mobilefirst application required those .jar file and java classes inside project.war.
What is the best possible solution?

Should add shared libraries to worklightconsole ?

Comment: why do you need to call you Projectname.war file from you deployed application can you explain why you need it ?

Comment: I need to call my libraries and jar files located on  projectname.war .

Comment: You cannot call a .war file from your client application. A .war file is a SERVER entity. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @JosephChristopherPimentel Libraries and jar files located in server side can be used only by server side things like adapter and authentication.

Comment: @JosephChristopherPimentel are you trying to have external jar file in your client side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MobileFirst project's .war file contains server-related information and is deployed to the underlying application server hosting the MobileFirst Server.

The application server has a Host name. This is the host name or IP address that the client application will attempt connecting to.

> How can we call myprojectmobilefirst.war?

You are not supposed to "call" this .war file. In fact, after deployment you should generally leave it alone.

> Does routing policy should be declare?

As this is about connecting the client application to the server; this is not related as well.

> What is the effective approach?

You need to explain what is the actual *problem* that you are experiencing.

- Are you previewing the application in the console and unable to connect to the server?
- Are you running the application on a device and unable to connect to the server?

If you are unable to connect to the server, double-check the server URL.

Comment: I'm currently viewing the app on the console of the actual mobilefirst server. How can  mobilefirst application installed in mobilefirstconsole  communicate with the project.war installed on the websphere ?  In the mobilefirst development server you only deploy it but in actual server you upload .war file.

Comment: Run As > Build setting and deploy target > tick the checkbox for communicating with external servers > input your external server's full URL (protocol, host, port, context root). This will build the app with the setup to talk to your external server.

Comment: you then need to deploy the project's war file first and once it's working on the remote server, to deploy the wlapp and adapter files to the external server as well.

Comment: I have upload the .wlapp and adapter Idan. I have a problem on .war . I cannont find Configuration Tool to upload war file to server. Do you have any resources or links i can download?

Comment: There is a Knowledge Center for IBM MobileFirst Platform. You should use it: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html

Comment: We have uploaded the war file idan . Thanks but we are encountering another issue 500 for the .war file url location.

Comment: I will mark this as solved.  To access the configuration tool you need to use VNC Viewer.